# TYPO3: Disable cookies before accepting consent

Tags: cookies, typoscript, typo3-9.x, cookieconsent

I am using the dp_cookieconsent extension from https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/dp_cookieconsent/ in my TYPO3 9.5. The consent is displayed correctly at the bottom of my page. My problem now is that cookies are always set, doesn't matter, if I confirmed the "Allow Cookies" button or not.

What I did so far:

1. I installed the extension
2. I added colors using the constant editor
3. I added a language translation using typoscript like described in the link above

Is there a way to deactivate cookies until the button in the consent is pressed. I am only using cookies which are set when using the TYPO3 contact form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I concluded, that an extension (reCAPTCHA) was setting the Cookies on my contact form. After removing the extension, no Cookies are set anymore.